# CSS transform property inherited or not?

Tags: css

Hi I have a question which i read from the official MDN page, which clearly shows the `transform` property is not inherited. But in most case this is not correct:

```css
    div{
      display:table;
      width:50%;
      margin:0 auto;
      transform:skewX(20deg);
      border:2px solid teal;   
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <article>transform is inherited or not?</article>
    </div>
```

from the above code sample, the text from `article` element is clearly effected by the `transform:skewX(20deg)` which i set from its parent `div`.

So my questions are:

1.Is that all the `transform` property will automatically apply to its child element? such as `scale() translate()`.

2.Is that the `transform` is an inherited property like `font-size`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

transform is not an inherited property. If you look into your devtools, you can easily see that. For instance, in chrome devtools, the computed property tab will show you that the value for your article is none.

However, according to the specs, a transform will create a new "coordinates space" for its children, that's what is happening in your example. The article's transform property's value is none, but that does not mean it's not affected by the transform of the parent.

Official spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering

Comment: thanks for your reply, the "coordinates space" is quite make sense regarding to my question, just wondering is there any reference about that?

Comment: I updated my post with a link to how transform is rendered

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about what inheritance really mean. If your `transform:skewX(20deg);` would be inherited down, then your div would be skewed 20 degrees, and your article would be skewed 40 degrees (20 + 20)

here's what that would look like:

```css
div{
  display:table;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform:skewX(20deg);
  border:2px solid teal;   
}

article{
  transform:skewX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <article>transform is inherited or not?</article>
</div>
```

So it's not really inherited, but somewhat closer to the behaviour of opacity, when the child "zero" for transform will be relative to the parent's just like the max opacity for a child would be the parent opacity (if you have a opacity 50% child on a 50% opacity parent, then visually the child is 25% opaque)
Except with transform you can undo that by applying the opposite value, which you cannot do with opacity (there's no such thing as opacity:200%)
here's what that looks like:

```css
div{
  display:table;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  transform:skewX(20deg);
  border:2px solid teal;   
}

article{
  transform:skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <article>transform is inherited or not?</article>
</div>
```