# Revert css transform

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in CSS to revert all transforms applied to parents?

I am looking for an alternative solution of `transform: scale(0.5)`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    /* Apply scaling to the parent div with transform origin set to top left */
    
    .parent {
      transform: scale(2);
      transform-origin: top left;
    }
    /* Apply scaling to the child div with transform origin set to top left */
    
    .child {
      transform: scale(0.5);
      transform-origin: top left;
    }
    /* Add some styling for better visibility */
    
    .parent,
    .child {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Scaling Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Parent div with a class of 'parent' -->
  <div class="parent">
    <h2>Parent</h2>
    <!-- Child div with a class of 'child' -->
    <div class="child">
      <h3>Child</h3>
      <!-- Content inside the child div -->
      <p>This is the content inside the child div.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you want the `.child` div to appear unaffected by the `.parent` `scale(2)`?

Comment: I believe you effectively have to invert each transform (in reverse order), I don't think there's a nice "reset all" in this case.

Comment: @disinfor yes, exactly

Comment: there is no other way around that. [read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603332/7543162) why not just use different properties of the parent that are not inherited?

Answer (score 0):

Updated version based on your answer to another user:
The best way to reverse a scale is to:

```css
.parent {
  transform: none;
}
.parent:hover .child {
   transform: none;
   transform-origin: top left;
}
```

You can test using this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      /* Apply scaling to the parent div with transform origin set to top left */

      .parent {
        transform: scale(2);
        transform-origin: top left;
      }
      /* Apply scaling to the child div with transform origin set to top left */
      .parent:hover {
        transform: none;
      }
      .parent:hover .child {
        transform: none;
        transform-origin: top left;
      }
      .child {
        transform: scale(0.5);
        transform-origin: top left;
      }
      /* Add some styling for better visibility */

      .parent,
      .child {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Scaling Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Parent div with a class of 'parent' -->
    <div class="parent">
      <h2>Parent</h2>
      <!-- Child div with a class of 'child' -->
      <div class="child">
        <h3>Child</h3>
        <!-- Content inside the child div -->
        <p>This is the content inside the child div.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If u hover over the content you will see that it will just reverse the sizing (you can apply `transition: transform 0.2s` to see it go back to original scale if u want).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for. Actually no other solution exist for my question

Comment: It seems like there isn't one from what I read, sorry for the confusion.